# node --v giving output but npm --v giving neither any output nor any error

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently faced trouble while installing ReactJS on windows. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Node a couple of times. However, 'node --version' gave output but no output was given in the case of 'npm --version', not even a warning that npm command not found, etc.
 I checked system variables too.([User variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CayJj.png) [System variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5YrC.png)). Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: it's windows 11.